# Excel protecting worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to protect a sheet in Excel, I have some rows and colums hidden. I don't wan't anyone else to unhide these. How Can I achieve this. This is the only thing I want to protect.

I'm working with Excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the review ribbon and select hide worksheet and select everything except format rows and format columns this will prevent the unhide feature from being available. Would that suffice?